# Octopress capitalization in new posts

Tags: markdown, jekyll, octopress

Today i updated my Octopress blog and when i run:

```
rake new_post["This is a test of title"]
```

It creates my markdown file in source/_post/2013-02-18-this-is-a-test-of-title.markdown, then i run:

```
rake generate
```

and

```
rake preview
```

And the post now have the title

```
This Is A Test Of Title
```

I review the source of the markdown and find that

```
...
title: "This is a test of title"
...
```

So the markdown is fine. Also in the web page i use the developer tools of Chrome to see if a css property has the value of 'capitalize' but it don't, the anchor looks like this

```
<a href="...">This Is A Test of Title</a>
```

So looks like the problem of capitalization cames from the framework.

In the wiki of imathis/octopress repostory https://github.com/imathis/octopress/issues/202 seems some people who post in other languages don't like this 'feature' and even in the Rakefile, imathis removed this line:

```
post.puts "title: \"#{title.gsub(/&/,'&amp;').titlecase}\""
```

for this one:

```
post.puts "title: \"#{title.gsub(/&/,'&amp;')}\""
```

for that commit, so i open my Rakefile and it has the last line so my file is up-to-date, but obviously the problem persists

Any idea to how to avoid that behavior in the titles of posts?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your _config.yml, find the line

```
titlecase: true       # Converts page and post titles to titlecase
```

and set it to false.

More info about [titlecase](http://daringfireball.net/2008/05/title_case). You can also look at `plugins/titlecase.rb` to see how it works.

Comment: This solved the problem, i didn't find it because i assume that i 'know' what i can find in my '_config.yml', but this obviously works